# Sending pictures on Socket Python

Tags: python, sockets, photo, datagram

I'm currently working on a project and I need to send a photo to another computer through Python. I'm using the module Socket but when I tried to send my photo, I got an error saying "A message sent to a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or another network boundary, or the buffer used to receive a datagram was smaller than the datagram itself" 
How can I fix that ?
Thanks

Comment: Stop trying to fit the whole thing in a single datagram. Either use stream sockets or break the file up manually into multiple datagrams. If you mean module `socket`, then the first part means `socket.SOCK_STREAM`. I don't know a module called `Socket` so I can't help with that.

Comment: Yes I meant the module called `socket` . However I initialize my main socket with `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)`. So I used `socket.SOCK_STREAM`...

Answer (score 1):

Your image is too big to be sent in one UDP packet. You need to split the image data into several packets that are sent individually.
socket.SOCK_STREAM instead of socket.SOCK_DGRAM. There you don't have to worry about packet sizes and ordering. Although you need to set buffer_size.

```
import random
import socket, select
from time import gmtime, strftime
from random import randint

imgcounter = 1
basename = "image%s.png"

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 6666

connected_clients_sockets = []

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
server_socket.listen(10)

connected_clients_sockets.append(server_socket)
buffer_size = 4096

while True:

    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(connected_clients_sockets, [], [])



    for sock in read_sockets:

        if sock == server_socket:

            sockfd, client_address = server_socket.accept()
            connected_clients_sockets.append(sockfd)

        else:
            try:
                print ' Buffer size is %s' % buffer_size
                data = sock.recv(buffer_size)
                txt = str(data)

                if txt.startswith('SIZE'):
                    tmp = txt.split()
                    size = int(tmp[1])

                    print 'got size'
                    print 'size is %s' % size

                    sock.send("GOT SIZE")
                    # Now set the buffer size for the image 
                    buffer_size = 40960000

                elif txt.startswith('BYE'):
                    sock.shutdown()

                elif data:

                    myfile = open(basename % imgcounter, 'wb')

                    # data = sock.recv(buffer_size)
                    if not data:
                        myfile.close()
                        break
                    myfile.write(data)
                    myfile.close()

                    sock.send("GOT IMAGE")
                    buffer_size = 4096
                    sock.shutdown()
            except:
                sock.close()
                connected_clients_sockets.remove(sock)
                continue
        imgcounter += 1
server_socket.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What code do I put on the client side ?

Answer (score 0):

Server code:

```
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("", 5005))
server_socket.listen(5)
import os


client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
print "Conencted to - ",address,"\n"
while (1):
    choice = client_socket.recv(1024)
    choice = int(choice)
    if(choice == 1):
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print "The following data was received - ",data
        print "Opening file - ",data
        fp = open(data,'rb')
        strng = fp.read()
        size = os.path.getsize(data)
        size = str(size)
        client_socket.send(size)
        client_socket.send (strng)
        #client_socket.close()

    if (choice == 2 or choice == 3):
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print "The following data was received - ",data
        print "Opening file - ",data
        img = open(data,'rb')
        while True:
            strng = img.read(512)
            if not strng:
                break
            client_socket.send(strng)
        img.close()
        print "Data sent successfully"
        exit()
```

Client Code:

Please refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking
This code will be paused until it receives data. As default all sockets are in blocking mode. You should make it non-blocking.

> In non-blocking mode, if a recv() call doesn’t find any data, or if a
>   send() call can’t immediately dispose of the data, an error exception
>   is raised; in blocking mode, the calls block until they can proceed.
>   s.setblocking(0) is equivalent to s.settimeout(0.0); s.setblocking(1)
>   is equivalent to s.settimeout(None).

Or:

put client_socket.settimeout(10.0) after while(1) and before client_socket.send(k)
write after while(1) -> c,a = client_socket.accept()
c.settimeout(10.0) -> then after that anywhere there is client_socket change it to "c"

Therefore:

```
client_socket.connect(("", 5005))
deadline = time.time() + 20.0
client_socket.settimeout(deadline - time.time())
#or
client_socket.setblocking(0)
```

All Code:

```
import socket,os
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("", 5005))
client_socket.settimeout(1.0)
k = ' '
size = 1024

while(1):
    print "Do you want to transfer a \n1.Text File\n2.Image\n3.Video\n"
    k = raw_input()
    client_socket.send(k)
    k = int (k)
    if(k == 1):
        print "Enter file name\n"
        strng = raw_input()
        client_socket.send(strng)
        size = client_socket.recv(1024)
        size = int(size)
        print "The file size is - ",size," bytes"
        size = size*2
        strng = client_socket.recv(size)
        print "\nThe contents of that file - "
        print strng

    if (k==2 or k==3):
        print "Enter file name of the image with extentsion (example: filename.jpg,filename.png or if a video file then filename.mpg etc) - "
        fname = raw_input()
        client_socket.send(fname)
        fname = 'documents/'+fname
        fp = open(fname,'w')
        while True:
            try:
                strng = client_socket.recv(512)
                if not strng:
                    break
            except timeout:
                continue
            fp.write(strng)
        fp.close()
        print "Data Received successfully"
        exit()
```

Comment: Hello, these codes don't work for me. When I execute them, all is perfectly working but when the picture is sent, it never enters the loop `if not strng:
                break` on the client side, so the photo isn't closed and I can't open it. Although, the data is correctly received as the file is not empty. Thanks

Comment: I really don"t know how to fix it, I tried many thing but it still doesn't work

Comment: I keep trying to run this code but it still doesn't work.....

Comment: @Armczbt I just see your comment, sorry for delay. I edited my answer in client side. As I mentioned you need to set timeout or set the socket as non blocking in order to prevent pausing from receiving file or image.  I hope it helps, please do not hesitate to ask if it does not work.

Comment: client_socket.recv(512) will be blocked until it receives something. If it receives nothing, then it waits.

But if you set a timeout then periodically that wait will throw an exception and you can do other stuff before trying to read again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly, It still doesn't work. I added the line `client_socket.setblocking(0)` and now I've got an error on the line `strng = client_socket.recv(512) ` : Non-blocking operation on a socket could not be completed immediately. I don't understand why

Comment: Did you add "except timeout: continue"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211747/discussion-between-armczbt-and-mahsa-hassankashi).